# SQL query running in PhpMyAdmin panel but not running in Php script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a query that is giving me a headache, its running when I put in phpmyadmin but not producing any output not even an error when ran put in a script, I cant say its the connection or anything, I have another file almost exactly as this one and it works flawlessly but not this one, at least even an error at this point would be appreciated, below is my script:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
$db = new Db_Connect();
$conn = $db->connect();




// get all comments table
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT sale_comments._id ,sale_comments._user_fk, 
                                 users._fname, users._lname, 
                                 sale_comments._comment,
                                 sale_comments._date_created 
                            FROM sale_comments, users 
                            WHERE sale_comments._user_fk = users._id 
                            ORDER BY sale_comments._date_created DESC ");
$result->execute();

$response["comments"] = array();
$result->bind_result($id, $user_fk, $fname, $lname, $comment, $date_created);


while($row = $result->fetch()) 
{
    $comment = array();
    $comment["id"] = $id;
    $comment["user_fk"] = $user_fk;
    $comment["fname"] =$fname;
    $comment["lname"] = $lname;  
    $comment["comment"] = $comment;
    $comment["date_created"] = $date_created;


    $response["message"] = "Loaded";
     $response["error"] = FALSE;
    array_push($response["comments"], $comment);

}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

And my other script which is running perfectly

```
<?php


 require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
$db = new Db_Connect();
$conn = $db->connect();




// get all products from products table
 $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT _id, _user_fk, _title, _description, _price, _currency,  _category, _location, _image, _date_created FROM sales  ORDER BY _date_created DESC");
$result->execute();

$response["sales"] = array();
$result->bind_result($id, $user_fk, $title, $description, $price, $currency, $category, $location, $image, $date_created);


while($row = $result->fetch()) 
{
    $sale = array();
    $sale["id"] = $id;
    $sale["user_fk"] = $user_fk;  
    $sale["title"] = $title;
    $sale["description"] =$description;
    $sale["price"] = $price;
    $sale["currency"] = $currency;
    $sale["category"] = $category;
    $sale["location"] = $location;
    $sale["image"] = $image;
    $sale["date_created"] = $date_created;


    $response["message"] = "Loaded";
    array_push($response["sales"], $sale);

}

echo json_encode($response);



?>
```

[image: Image showing both my files are in the same folder]

[image: Image showing the same query running in phpmyadmin]

[image: Image showing the file not displaying anything when ran in browser]

Comment: MySQL connection has been established or not??

Comment: Yes, look at the second script, everything is the same except for the query and variables

Comment: Are the files in the same folder?

Comment: what error you are getting can you please post here?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: @AlbertAkki its not giving any error, its simply not giving any response, nothing at all

Comment: @Sarcoma yes they are

Comment: In phpmyadmin, do you receive any output? I mean are there any rows returned?

Comment: try to enable error log as @RiggsFolly posted as above

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added and still nothing at all

Comment: I may be wrong but would it not be better using a join? `SELECT s._id , s._user_fk, u._fname, u._lname, s._comment, s._date_created FROM sale_comments as s JOIN users as u on u.id = s._user_id ORDER BY s._date_created DESC`

Comment: @Blinkydamo You are not wrong, but the query as it is should still run and OP says it works in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Are you sure its actually being run? Check your AJAX call is actually calling this script

Comment: The only difference I can spot, is the space after DESC in the first string. Can't see that it should make any difference at all but worth a shot.

Comment: @yogurt look at the added images

Comment: @Blinkydamo thank you, I am not familiar with joins so I try by all means to avoid them

Comment: @RiggsFolly look at the images please

Comment: Images do not prove you are actually calling this script from your AJAX call

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not understand what you mean by that but the idea is this is the server side of my android app, I call these from Android, and all ther other files work except this one.

Comment: Ok sorry, make sure your android code is calling the correct script

Comment: @RiggsFolly but am calling echo on the json array, isnt it suppose to print out even in browser?

Comment: Can you also check the HTTP status code if it's 500 or 200?

Comment: am not getting any http error too, its just not sending back the data

Comment: _isnt it suppose to print out even in browser_ yes it is

Comment: @RiggsFolly up to now no luck

Comment: Did you actually add the code I suggested to cause errors to be shown on the browser page

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I did, tried removing the variables that receive the data during loop and its looking exaclty the number of rows its suppose to, thats 2 the issue is, its somehow failing to assign the data to the json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, very stupid mistake i should say, the code is ok, well the logic I mean, the issue was my variable naming,

I declared $comment in bind as a field

```
$result->bind_result($id, $user_fk, $fname, $lname, $comment, $date_created);
```

Then I went on and mistakenly declared it as the array that was to host the data produced by the query, at the end of the day it was consuming itself :D thanks everyone for you answers next time I will be extra careful

```
$comment = array();
$comment["id"] = $id;
$comment["user_fk"] = $user_fk;
$comment["fname"] =$fname;
$comment["lname"] = $lname;  
$comment["comment"] = $comment;
$comment["date_created"] = $date_created;




 $result->bind_result($id, $user_fk, $fname, $lname, $comment, $date_created);
while($row = $result->fetch()) 
{
    $commentArray = array();
    $commentArray["id"] = $id;
    $commentArray["user_fk"] = $user_fk;
    $commentArray["fname"] =$fname;
    $commentArray["lname"] = $lname;  
    $commentArray["comment"] = $comment;
    $commentArray["date_created"] = $date_created;


    $response["message"] = "Loaded";
     $response["error"] = FALSE;
    array_push($response["comments"], $commentArray);

}`
```

Comment: So obvious now you've found it.